# Redstone mechanism that deactivates when another one is activated

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a build in progress and it contains things like gates, big doors and other redstone related stuff. I was interested in making it so that only one gate/door can be closed at one time, and when another one is closed the first one will be automatically opened.

Is it possible to build something that works like that or similiar?

Comment: I assume your gates have two buttons, a close one and an open one, yes? Since your case is only one closed, make it so the button to close is attached to every other opening circuit of all of the other doors; If they are open, they'll keep open and if they are closed, they will keep closed. If your doors aren't a two option like I mentioned, I'd have to see how they work for a better answer i guess.

Comment: If there are only 2 gates, you could make a simple NOT gate using a sticky piston and a redstone block. Then you could just control it with a lever, if it's off, the NOT gate will power the opening circuit of gate 1, if it's on, the lever will shut off the NOT gate's power and also power the opening circuit of gates.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Block Key: Red block=redstone block, grey block with brown and green=sticky piston red line= redstone dust, brown rectangle with grey thing= door.

Now if you activate the sticky piston, door A will open and door B will close. notice that you don't have to connect doors to it. you can use any redstone device.

Comment: For future notice, you can edit answers that you have already posted rather than posting a new version and deleting the old one. Deleted answers are never really deleted, they're just "hidden" to the general public, and not to experienced users and moderators. For conciseness, clarity, and organization, it would be preferable to edit in the future rather than repost.